# Force the use of a modifier key in order to drag/move files in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, accessibility, click

**Disclaimer**: *I have actual clinically diagnosed OCD, so please, excuse my request if you find it silly, thank you.*

Sometimes I misclick while using Finder, and as a result, files are dragged and moved between folders, or I double click to open a file and instead it gets me to rename it.

Can I use Terminal, or some kind of script, to prevent Finder from click-drag-moving or renaming files (unless a user defined modifier key is pressed at the same time, like <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>)

There's the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button in order to cancel an action, indeed, (as well as the Undo function), but unfortunately due to my OCD, it doesn't reassure me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with customizing the UI if you use one of several "Finder alternatives". I googled "Mac replace Finder" and got several articles with titles like "Best Finder alternative solutions for Mac in 2023".

I don't know how they work, whether they may already have such a feature, whether they completely replace the Finder app, whether Finder will still control your Desktop icons, etc., but they may be a place to start. Some of them may even have developers who are sympathetic and would add your request as a customization feature in an upcoming release of their product. It doesn't hurt to ask.

Speaking of it "hurting to ask", my apologies on behalf of "user3439894" who obviously didn't either read or understand the disclaimer at the top of your question. Perhaps they have their own undiagnosed issues about how saying "that *I* know of" should be understood to be the last word on a subject.